# Convert jsonb in PostgreSQL to rows without cycle

Tags: postgresql

ffI have a json array stored in my postgres database. The first table "Orders" looks like this:

```
order_id, basket_items_id
1, {1,2}
2, {3}
3, {1,2,3,1}
```

Second table "Items" looks like this:

```
item_id, price
1,5
2,3
3,20
```

Already tried to load data with multiple sql and select of different jsonb record, but this is not a silver bullet.

```
SELECT
sum(price)
FROM orders
INNER JOIN items on
orders.basket_items_id = items.item_id
WHERE order_id = 3;
```

Want to get this as output:

```
order_id, basket_items_id, price
1, 1, 5
1, 2, 3
2, 3, 20
3, 1, 5
3, 2, 3
3, 3, 20
3, 1, 5
```

or this:

```
order_id, sum(price)
1, 8
2, 20
3, 33
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=6f0e3daa7c7a9cc10b76e66fa088c8de)

```
SELECT
    o.order_id,
    elems.value::int as basket_items_id,
    i.price
FROM
    orders o, jsonb_array_elements_text(basket_items_id) as elems
LEFT JOIN items i 
ON i.item_id = elems.value::int
ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

1. `jsonb_array_elements_text` expands the jsonb array into one row each element. With this you are able to join against your second table directly
2. Since the expanded array gives you `text` elements you have to cast them into integers using `::int`

Of course you can `GROUP` and `SUM` aggregate this as well:

```
SELECT
    o.order_id,
    SUM(i.price)
FROM
    orders o, jsonb_array_elements_text(basket_items_id) as elems
LEFT JOIN items i 
ON i.item_id = elems.value::int
GROUP BY o.order_id
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Thx for elegant solution!

Answer (score 1):

Is your `orders.basket_items_id` column of type `jsonb` or `int[]`?

If the type is `jsonb` you can use [`json_array_elements_text`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-json.html) to expand the column:

```
SELECT
    o.order_id,
    o.basket_item_id,
    items.price
FROM
(
    SELECT
        order_id,
        jsonb_array_elements_text(basket_items_id)::int basket_item_id
    FROM
        orders
) o
JOIN
    items ON o.basket_item_id = items.item_id
ORDER BY
    1, 2, 3;
```

See [this DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/egHvEPyZb215j1bVWHbHyc/1).

If the type is `int[]` (array of integers), you can run a similar query with the [`unnest`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-array.html) function:

```
SELECT
    o.order_id,
    o.basket_item_id,
    items.price
FROM
(
    SELECT
        order_id,
        unnest(basket_items_id) basket_item_id
    FROM
        orders
) o
JOIN
    items ON o.basket_item_id = items.item_id
ORDER BY 
    1, 2, 3;
```

See [this DB-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qToUcdASFkCtx9DroBsa5k/1)